# Capacitor filter optimization for ATmega32U2 board

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, power, capacitor, pcb

I've been working on a project built around a ATmega32U2 with a PMW3360DMâ€T2QU optical sensor and I have some questions on where and when capacitor to ground filters are necessary.

Many of the datasheets for the components I am using recommend capacitor filters at their input and output. I believe some of them may be redundant or just unnecessary, but I'm not completely sure how to determine when they are truly necessary or not.

On my current schematic, I have some capacitor filters that I feel may be unnecessary or redundant, such as the second filter(C8) on the 1.9v line leading to the VDD and LED_P pins on the sensor(U3). The duplicate 1uF capacitor(C5) on the 5v line feeding the 1.9v voltage regulator I also feel may be redundant due to the 5v input from the USB already having a filter on it(C2) between the USB input and the MCU(U1).

How can I tell when a capacitor filter is needed, beyond when a datasheet recommends it and when can and can't I combine duplicate capacitor filters on the same line? Is it mostly a matter of closeness/relative location on the PCB or trace length from input to output? As I understand it currently most datasheets recommend a filter on the input and the output of their device, would this mean that when using multiple devices together that I can skip one of the filters on a line between them because the output of the first device already has a filter on it before going to the input of the second device(Like on the 1.9v line with C8 to the sensor VDD/LED_P pins)? Could I just skip putting a filter on the output of devices and only put a filter on the input that they feed into instead, or does this not work due to trace lengths and noise? Is it possible to combine 2 close filters going to neighboring pins(Like on the 3.3v line with C3,4,7 from the MCU's internal 3.3v regulator to the MCU's VCC+AVCC)? Also, is there a way to determine when a filter is needed, and a proper capacitor rating for it without doing physical testing yourself of prototype boards?

Here is a picture of my current schematic:[image]

I am creating a very lightweight and low profile PCB, so eliminating and optimizing every part possible is beneficial.

Any amount of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some reasons why you can't combine parallel capacitors (1) Power supply decoupling capacitors for a certain IC need to be close to the IC they are decoupling, for the smallest loop possible. So each IC needs it's own capacitor(s). (2) Multiple, different value, capacitors in parallel each handle a different frequency range. Replacing with 1 larger value capacitor will not have the same effect.

Comment: There are bigger things to worry about first. What is the AVR supply voltage and does it run at 16 MHz at that voltage? The ISP connector has 5V reference but if the AVR supply is less then would not that fry the AVR? And will the ISP programming work if there is a chip on the same bus, I don't see it being made sure it is disabled during programming. There is no cap on reset pin, which is typically suggested. And the other pushbuttons short circuit the supply to ground.